# CSS p {Indent} Leaving a gap

Tags: html, css, indentation

I am trying to make a website that has a contents page.

I use the `<a href="chapter1">go to chapter 1</a>` as the contents part,
and when it clicks it does to the `<a name="chapter1"><u>Chapter 1</u></a>`

This works well, but there's 1 catch (there's always a catch)...
I want to make it look like the ones on Wikipedia:

[View Image][1]
[1]: http://crystalanalysis.anydns.com/images/wikipedia_contents.png

But I didn't want to copy the one from Wikipedia, I wanted to make my own,
I looked around, found the parts I needed and had 2 problems! The  first problem I am
having has something to do with the Indent. I tried using the p.indent {text-indent:150px}
but it only did the indent for the line I put it before. So:

Indented text

But it was annoying having to put the Indented text before every single line in the
contents box, but it works:

```
<header>
    p.contenttitle {text-indent:50px;} 
    p.contentsub {text-indent:100px;} 
</header>

<body>
    <div style="background-color:#FFFFFF;width:1024;border:solid 1px #000000;"><br>
    <font class=Blackverdana><b>Contents:</b><br></font>
    <div align="left">
    <!-- CONTENTS a href --><font class=Blackverdana>
    <p class=contenttitle><a href="#C0.1">Chapter 00: First things first...</a>
    <p class=contentsub><a href="#C0.2">Chapter 0.2 Finding the SDK for your game</a>
    <p class=contentsub><a href="#C0.3">Chapter 0.3 Running the Hammer Editor</a>
    <p class=contentsub><a href="#C0.4">Chapter 0.4 First Load</a><br><br>
</body>
```

The other problem I am having is that if you look at the contents page:
http://crystalanalysis.anydns.com/7-12-2013.html

you will see that there seems to be some sort of `<br>` after every line.
I did not plan to have those there, they just appeared. Maybe a connotation with the "p" tag?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

And also the website is a blog and I am making a Hammer Editor Tutorial if anyone was wondering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that you aren't ending the

tags when you first start them.. An example of this:

```
<p class=contenttitle><a href="#C0.1">Chapter 00: First things first...</a>
```

When in all reality it should be:

```
<p class=contenttitle><a href="#C0.1">Chapter 00: First things first...</a></p>
```

That could be a possible issue, as well as you should really look into using a CSS page to reference your HTML. Creating a class/id will actually make that indentation process ten times easier. For more information on that I can provide a handy link from w3.org that can explain the entire process of using CSS and how it can make your life a lot easier!

http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/011/firstcss.en.html

Comment: I just added </p> to the end of each class but it didn't seem to change much. Thanks for all the information anyway, it's nice to know that I can visit a website and get help that I can actually use +1

Comment: Definitely! You should learn to use a separate CSS page because it will make everything much cleaner and much easier to handle. You are doing inline CSS, which can get to be much more complicated than just creating a separate page. If you want a good book, I would suggest this one: http://www.amazon.com/HTML-CSS-Design-Build-Websites/dp/1118008189/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1386444083&sr=8-1&keywords=HTML+and+CSS

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was planning on doing external CSS pages but I guess I should add them now before I finish the website or else I will never get around to it before it's too late. And thanks for the book idea. Maybe a book for christmas!

Comment: I mean, external CSS will make your life ten times easier when it comes to creating this web page. If you want something that is more for "now" here is another great website to reference until you get the book: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/  This will give you an idea of how to use a lot of stuff that CSS can do.

Comment: Thanks, I just added an External Style Sheet to my website, it really does make the HTML files 45% cleaner, and gives me time to actually organize the structure of everything rather than having it all messily sitting at random spots on the text doc. thanks again.